# How to move a shape using the accelerometer sensor? Android java

Tags: android, accelerometer, shapes

I am finding it difficult in understanding how I can use the android accelerometer to move a simple rectangle shape, I have registered the sensor but I do not know how to code the rectangle shape to make it move with the android accelerometer, If anyone could help me with this whether its a tutorial or just ideas it would be very helpful, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why dont you just try the "AccelerometerPlay" sample project provided in the folder "samples" in the Android SDK. 
Just import it and see how a circlular object is moved in it using the accelerometer.